# Wordpress min image dimension in upload

Tags: wordpress

In setttings -> media are settings to set max image size, but I need to set min size it's possible ? Or maybe are some function

Comment: Hi, please remember to always Google first. Searching `Wordpress min image dimension in upload` gives me a number of promising results.

Comment: For example this: [How to Require a Minimum Image Dimension for Uploading?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/28359)

Answer (score 0):

There's a question on the WordPress Stack Exchange site that has some useful information -- you'll want to add a filter on `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` and then add a function to check the dimensions:

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter','tc_handle_upload_prefilter');
```

Here's the question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28359/how-to-require-a-minimum-image-dimension-for-uploading

Comment: I vant set static image size for small 200x300 and for medium 500x300 it's possible with this filter ?

Comment: That's a different question -- this page has a bunch of helpful code and links to plugins that will be helpful in doing that: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-additional-image-sizes-in-wordpress/